# Create and fill elements in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I am new to **C#** and trying to learn it on my own. I came up with a solution to this problem.

> Given an integer size, return array of length size filled with 1s.

Is there a more concise way of doing this?

```cs
int[] createArray(int size)
{
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        al.Add(1);
    int[] myArray = al.Cast<int>().ToArray();
    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: `al.Cast<int>().ToArray();`, hmm, you could actually create a `List<int>()` then do a `ToArray()` on it. shorten the type casting a bit.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using an `ArrayList` rather than an array or `List<T>`?

Comment: In the meantime, I'd suggest reading up on `Enumerable.Repeat` and `ToArray`. Or alternatively (since you are new to C#), how to declare an array and `for` loops (to populate the array).

Comment: Is there a reason for using ArrayList?

No, its just what I came up with while searching Google to figure this out.  I'm new so I don't know the best way to go about this or to make this more concise.

Comment: Your problem here is threefold. a) How do I define an array of a specific size? b) How do I loop through an array? c) How do I set an element in an array? I'd suggest attacking each of those three problems, one by one.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do if it was C++

`std::vector<int>createArray(int size){
  vector<int> v(size, 1);
  return v;
}
`

Sorry, still trying to learn the markdown on this site.

Comment: What is necessary is to initialize a new array and return it.  That array must be the length defined by the size, and each element must have 1 as its value (or is it key?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elegant way:

```
int size = 10;
int defaultValue = 1;
int[] myArray = Enumerable.Repeat<int>(defaultValue, size).ToArray();
// short way:
int[] myArray2 = Enumerable.Repeat<int>(1, 10).ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the `<int>` since the type will be inferred. Just do `var array = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 10).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this

```
int[] createArray(int size)
{
    int[] myArray = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        myArray[i] = 1;
     return myArray;
}
```

Comment: That is a cleaner way of what I did, but was not what I was looking for.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

This was what I was looking for.  Thanks for all the help.

```
int[] createArray(int size) 
{
  return Enumerable.Repeat(1, size).ToArray();
}
```